# Bluetooth LE sensors vs laptops BLE, differences in signal strength?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

My project group and I are developing a Bluetooth application at college. We have received some very complicated sensors and need to get started with testing, so we might have to test using other Bluetooth devices than sensors at first.

What would be the difference in signal strength and likewise between a laptop computer and a Bluetooth sensor? Would the signal strength of the laptop be weaker since Bluetooth transmitting isn't its main purpose?

Comment: Yes, it can be but for BLE it will not be too big difference. Usually any sensor that advertises RSSI (and that was developed to measure distance) also advertises "calibrated" RSSI value that allows to calculate distance.

Comment: I would say use a smartphone. They usually have superior receiver sensitivity and good antennas. If you buy some Bluetooth module / devkit then they are most likely worse since they are often designed for cheap products with coin cell batteries in mind. Worst of all however are tiny usb dongles.